# ScrollTOP com o campo que está em foco

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando saber o tamanho em px do campo input com foco ao top da tela. Para dar um scrollTOP e o campo em foco ficar no topo da tela.

A ideia do problema é seguinte:

Estou trabalhando mobile, e estou utilizando metodos hibridos para desenvolver, por este motivo tenho `HTML5`, `CSS3` ,`JQUERY` entre outros meio web de desenvolver. Preciso de uma solução generica para que qualquer pagina que a pessoa estiver navegando, ele pegue o campo que está sendo digitado e coloque no topo da pagina. A pagina no sentido de `div`, pois cada `div` é uma `view`, a `div` que está sendo visualizada tem o `display: block` porem as restantes ficam com `display: none`.

Mediante as especificações como desenvolver ?

Eu comecei a fazer algumas coisas porem não sei continuar, segue o código:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
is_keyboard = (window.innerHeight < initial_screen_size);
is_landscape = (screen.height < screen.width);

updateViews();
}, false);

function updateViews() {
 // $("#ajusteTeclado").show();
  console.log("Entro aqui.");

    var elmnt = document.getElementById("login");
    elmnt.scrollTop = 500;

  $('#login').css('top','100px');

}
```

Porem conforme utilizei é tudo manual preciso pegar do campo em foco.

Comment: O campo que recebe um `focus` fica centrado/visivel no browser certo? Não percebi bem o que não estás a conseguir fazer...

Comment: @Sergio Na verdade estou trabalhando com mobile, e tenho vários campos na tela, a minha ideia é quando clica ne algum input qualquer que seja ele, suba para o top da pagina. O motivo é para dar melhor visibilidade para o que o cara esta digitando.

Comment: Então queres fazer um scroll para que o input fique no topo da página é isso?

Comment: Exatamente isto que preciso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um [jsFiddle para testar o teu problema](https://jsfiddle.net/vb7w4m51/). Não sei se abordo o problema que estás a ter, mas repara que medir o `.scrollTop();` de um elemento que recebe um focus vai dar erro, pois o evento é disparado antes de o elemento e scroll estar no sitio certo.

```
$(inputs).on('focus', function () {
    // repara que o focus dispara antes de fazer scroll 
    // e por isso o .scrollTop() pode ser errado! 
    var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var input = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        var scrollTardio = $(document).scrollTop();
        input.value = scrollTardio;
        console.log(scroll, scrollTardio); // valores diferentes!
    }, 10);
});
```

Para fazeres um scroll para o elemento, tendo em conta a sua altura, precisas saber a posição do elemento na página e aplicar isso ao scroll.

Podes fazer assim:

```
$(inputs).on('focus', function () {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    $(document).scrollTop(pos.top);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vb7w4m51/1/

Comment: Infelismente não funcionou com meu problema, acho porque o que está no top é a div. Na verdade nem movimento nada na tela ao testar.

Comment: Estou pensando em utilizar o parent para pegar a div que o input está sera que funciona ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues sim, pode ser uma boa ideia, algo como `$(this).parent().offset();` ou `$(this).closest('.classe').offset();`.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar jQuery para para calcular a distância ao topo, e após usar a função [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) para "levar o input para cima". Ficaria assim:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$( "input" ).focus(function() {
     var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $(this).offset().top,
        distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
    
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, distance);

  });
});//]]> 

</script>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
```

Neste exemplo, você "pega" o evento [focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) do jQuery, e calcula a distância do elemento em destaque ao topo da página. Ao calcular esta distância, apenas adiciona ele no `scrollTop`.

Segue [este exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/Lgcq615r/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery para isso.

```
var el = $("#seuidentificador");

el.stop().animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing', function() { 

   console.log("Funcionou!!!");

});
```

Onde, seu **seuidentificador** é o seu input.

Se você não tiver um identificador no input, é só você varrer os elementos e verificar qual input está com focus.

Comment: Porem é o seguinte, tenho vários campos, e possuo varias divs, na como é mobile a div que fiz em display: block é a que está sendo utilizada a restante fica display: none

Comment: kkkk mais é exatamente isto que é a minha duvida, saber qual é o foco

Comment: Os inputs são em sequência? A ideia que você quer, é o cara ir preenchendo os inputs e fazendo como se fosse um next no input?

Comment: na verdade não, porque acontece o seguinte, quando eu vou digitar algo no mobile, o teclado que sobe tampa o campo, para solucionar isto eu pensei em colocar o campo com foco no topo da pagina. e quando não estive-se ele voltaria normal.